# How to exclude multiple patterns using python behave

Tags: python, python-behave

I have 10 feature files out of which I want to exclude api.feature and integration.feature .  How do I do it using behave?

```
behave --tags @test --no-capture --show-timings  -e (int|u)

behave --tags @test --no-capture --show-timings  -e api.feature -e integration.feature
```

None of the above 2 options work.

Comment: I actually have behave setup. I copied out one of my feature files and renamed it to bob.feature. I executed the following command, and of my three feature files, only bob.feature was executed: `behave features/ -e some_other`

Comment: -e works for me when I have to exclude only 1 pattern. How do I exclude multiple patterns? For. eg above, I have 2 files api.feature and integration.feature    .  How do I tell behave to exclude these 2 files in 1 pattern string  ? or by specifying complete filenames (multiple patterns) ?

Comment: I just re-read the documentation and even looked back at the answer posted and it hit me. It's expecting a regex pattern: `behave -e "(api|integration)"`. With that, you can add as much complexity as you want to filter out what you don't want.

Comment: Thank you  "idjaw". It worked!

Comment: idjaw , Could you please point me to which documentation you looked at?

Comment: [here](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/behave.html#cmdoption-e). "regular expression pattern". When I saw that I decided to give it a regex and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
-e, --exclude
```

Don’t run feature files matching regular expression PATTERN.

this answer was taken from [here](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/behave.html)

Comment: OP mentioned in their question the `-e` was not working for them.

Comment: I do see that but I was not sure if OP is using the right pattern

Comment: I will delete this post if necessary.

Comment: No no. No need. You actually might be right. Because I tested on my end. I have Behave set up. And -e is working for me.

Comment: Take a look at my comment in the original post. If OP confirms that is it, feel free to just put it in your answer to make yours complete. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, but made a small mistake in your first example.

Behave [supports](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/regular_expressions.html) ordinary re syntax as Python does.
So in any [place](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/behave.html#command-line-arguments), where we see PATTERN reference, we can use it.

"|" is used for "OR" condition and I think the problem was that your shell interpreted it as a 'pipe' character. So we need to escape it with "\" character.
Correct call should be next:

```
behave --tags @test --no-capture --show-timings  -e int\|u
```